# Guaranteeing the visibility of side effects of concurrent tasks in the Java Execution Framework

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, locks

I am experimenting with techniques for ensuring the visibility of side effects accomplished by concurrent tasks executed using the Java Executor framework.
As a simple scenario, considere an hypothetic problem of matrix multiplication.

Let's say that the matrices to multiply could be considerably large (e.g., few thousands rows and columns) and that to speed up the multiplication of such matrices I implement a concurrent algorithm where the calculation of each cell in the result matrix is considered as an independent (i.e., parallelizable) task.
To simplify a bit, let's ignore that for small input matrices this parallelization may be not such a good idea.

So considere below the first version of my program:

```
public class MatrixMultiplier {

    private final int[][] m;
    private final int[][] n;
    private volatile int[][] result; //the (lazily computed) result of the matrix multiplication

    private final int numberOfMRows; //number of rows in M
    private final int numberOfNColumns; //number of columns in N
    private final int commonMatrixDimension; //number of columns in M and rows in N

    public MatrixMultiplier(int[][] m, int[][] n) {
        if(m[0].length != n.length)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Uncompatible arguments: " + Arrays.toString(m) + " and " + Arrays.toString(n));
        this.m = m;
        this.n = n;
        this.numberOfMRows = m.length;
        this.numberOfNColumns = n[0].length;
        this.commonMatrixDimension = n.length;
    }

    public synchronized int[][] multiply() {
        if (result == null) {
            result = new int[numberOfMRows][numberOfNColumns];

            ExecutorService executor = createExecutor();

            Collection<Callable<Void>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMRows; i++) {
                final int finalI = i;
                for (int j = 0; j < numberOfNColumns; j++) {
                    final int finalJ = j;
                    tasks.add(new Callable<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public Void call() throws Exception {
                            calculateCell(finalI, finalJ);
                            return null;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            try {
                executor.invokeAll(tasks);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } finally {
                executor.shutdownNow();
            }

        }

        return result;
    }

    private ExecutorService createExecutor() {
        final int availableProcessors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        final int processorsBound = availableProcessors + 1;
        final int maxConcurrency = numberOfMRows * numberOfNColumns;
        final int threadPoolSize = maxConcurrency < processorsBound ? maxConcurrency : processorsBound;
        return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);
    }

    private void calculateCell(int mRow, int nColumn) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < commonMatrixDimension; k++) {
            sum += m[mRow][k] * n[k][nColumn];
        }
        result[mRow][nColumn] = sum;
    }

}
```

As far as I understand there is a problem with this implementation: some modifications to the `result` matrix by the executed tasks may not be necessarily visible to the thread invoking `multiply()`.

Assuming the previous is correct, consider the alternative implementation of `multiply()` relying on explicit locks (the new lock related code is commented with `//<LRC>`):

```
    public synchronized int[][] multiply() {
        if (result == null) {
            result = new int[numberOfMRows][numberOfNColumns];

            final Lock[][] locks = new Lock[numberOfMRows][numberOfNColumns]; //<LRC>
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMRows; i++) { //<LRC>
                for (int j = 0; j < numberOfNColumns; j++) { //<LRC>
                    locks[i][j] = new ReentrantLock(); //<LRC>
                } //<LRC>
            } //<LRC>

            ExecutorService executor = createExecutor();

            Collection<Callable<Void>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMRows; i++) {
                final int finalI = i;
                for (int j = 0; j < numberOfNColumns; j++) {
                    final int finalJ = j;
                    tasks.add(new Callable<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public Void call() throws Exception {
                            try { //<LRC>
                                locks[finalI][finalJ].lock(); //<LRC>
                                calculateCell(finalI, finalJ);
                            } finally { //<LRC>
                                locks[finalI][finalJ].unlock(); //<LRC>
                            } //<LRC>
                            return null;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            try {
                executor.invokeAll(tasks);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } finally {
                executor.shutdownNow();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMRows; i++) { //<LRC>
                for (int j = 0; j < numberOfNColumns; j++) { //<LRC>
                    locks[i][j].lock(); //<LRC>
                    locks[i][j].unlock(); //<LRC>
                } //<LRC>
            } //<LRC>
        }

        return result;
    }
```

The usage of explicit locks above has as unique goal to ensure the publication of the changes to the invoking thread, since there is no any possibility of contention.

My main question is if this is a valid solution to the problem of publishing side effects in my scenario.

As a secondary question: is there a more efficient/elegant way to solve this problem ? Please note that I am not looking for alternative algorithm implementations (e.g., the Strassen's algorithm) for parallelizing matrix multiplication, since mine is just a simple case study. I am rather interested on alternatives for ensuring the visibility of changes in an algorithm like the one presented here.

**UPDATE**

I think the alternative implementation below improves on the previous implementation. It makes use of one single internal lock without affecting much the concurrency:

```
public class MatrixMultiplier {
    ...
    private final Object internalLock = new Object();

    public synchronized int[][] multiply() {
        if (result == null) {
            result = new int[numberOfMRows][numberOfNColumns];

            ExecutorService executor = createExecutor();

            Collection<Callable<Void>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMRows; i++) {
                final int finalI = i;
                for (int j = 0; j < numberOfNColumns; j++) {
                    final int finalJ = j;
                    tasks.add(new Callable<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public Void call() throws Exception {
                            calculateCell(finalI, finalJ);
                            synchronized (internalLock){}
                            return null;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            try {
                executor.invokeAll(tasks);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } finally {
                executor.shutdownNow();
            }

        }

        synchronized (internalLock){}

        return result;
    }
    ...
}
```

This alternative is just more efficient but both it and the previous implementation which makes use of many locks look correct to me. Are all my observations correct ? Is there a more efficient/elegant way to deal with the synchronization problem in my scenario?

Comment: Can you have these tasks be decomposed for the Fork Join framework?  It takes care of all these types of visibility issues you see.

Comment: all the visibility issues are automatically solved by means of using the Fork/Join framework ? I did not know that, thanks for the hint. This may answer my secondary question, but not the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring `result` as `volatile` only ensures that changing the reference of `result` (i.e. `result = ...;` operations) is visible to everyone.

The most obvious way to resolve this is to eliminate the side effect. In this case this is easy: just make `calculateCell()` and the `Callable` invoking it return the value and let the main thread write the values into the array.

You could of course do explicit locking, like you did in your second example but it seems an overkill to use `nxm` locks when you could use just one lock. Of course one lock would kill the parallelism in your example, so once again the solution is to make `calculateCell()` return the value and only lock for the duration of writing the result in the `result` array.

Or indeed you can use `ForkJoin` and forget about the whole thing because it will do it for you.

Comment: I think we agree regarding the `volatile` declaration of `result`, it is needed, but just to ensure that the tasks can see the array assigned to `result`. I am also aware that I can use a result returned from Callable and copy such result back in the original array, but it looks quite inefficient if the array is very large as in my scenario :( . Regarding the amount of locks, I have just updated my question with an alternative that makes use of only one lock without affecting much the concurrency.

Comment: @Sergio Why do you think it is inefficient for the `Callable` to return the result? The overwhelming majority of the time spent should still be in the `calculateResult()` method, which does run in parallel.

Comment: sorry, you are right, got confused somewhere. It is a single scalar value (not an array) so it is fine to just return it (with the minor complication that its position in the result array needs to be calculated). Thanks for the correction @biziclop. In any case, do you think that my two alternative implementations are "functionally" correct? (although what you propose seems to be a better alternative).